# Display the particular rows in datagridview selected by the treeview control

Tags: c#, datagridview, treeview

I have trying to update datagridview based on the node selection in the treeviewcontrol.For example if i select the node wit the value 13 in the treeviewcontrol then it should display all the datagridview rows with the id=13 and clear all the other rows.I have started the code but i don't know where to go from here.Here is the code.

```
   private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int outva;
        if (int.TryParse((e.Node.Text), out outva))
        {
            save=Convert.ToInt16(e.Node.Text);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            int row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
            {
                if (save == Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    dataGridView1[0, i].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is [DataSourse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) in your `GridView`?

Populating grid with `dataGridView1.Rows.Add` is not a good choice for your task. The better way is to create a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx), fill it with needed data, set it as `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`, and use [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)  for `DataTable.DefaultView`.

Why are you making `int.TryParse` and then `Convert.ToInt16`, if `Int16.MaxValue < id`and `id < int.MaxValue` then you will take an exception. Use this `if` statment `if (Int16.TryParse((e.Node.Text), out save))`